# Removing extra spaces from column header

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress GridControl in my C# WPF application.
I've property names like ProductType, ProductCategory etc .in my collection that is being used as ItemSource to this grid.(AutoGeneratingColumn is set to true.)
But I see that the grid adds extra space between words in the column header caption...for e.g. Product Type, Product Category etc.

Is there any way I can remove spaces that appear in the captions?

I did try the following but no luck:

```
e.column.ColumnChooserHeaderCaption= e.column.FieldName;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress WPF Grid:

```
//If this property is null the bound FieldName will be used with spaces between capitals
BaseColumn.Header = "Custom Header";
```

DevExpress WinForms Grid:

```
//Same details apply if null as in WPF example
GridColumn.Caption = "Custom Header";
```